# How to pass string as parameter to Golang pointer receiver function?

Tags: go

I am trying one simple Go struct with value and pointer receiver functions. I am not able to pass one string as an argument to pointer receiver function to modify the struct data. Can anyone please help on this?

Code:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
)

type book struct {
    author   string
    name     string
    category string
    price    int16
}

func (b book) greet() string {
    return "Welcome " + b.author
}

func (b *book) changeAuthor(author string) {
   b.author = author
}

func main() {
    book := book{author: "Arockia",
        name:     "Python shortcuts",
        category: "IT",
        price:    1500}
    fmt.Println(book.author)
    fmt.Println(book.greet())
    fmt.Println(book.changeAuthor("arulnathan"))
    fmt.Println(book.author)
}
```

Error:

> .\struct_sample.go:29:31: book.changeAuthor(string("arulnathan")) used as value

Answer (score 3):

```
func (b *book) changeAuthor(author string) {
   b.author = author
}
```

`changeAuthor` does not have a return type. You cannot use `Println` or any other function/method which expects a parameter in your case.

To solve this, first you can change your author as `book.changeAuthor("arulnathan")` and the print `book.author`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not print `changeAuthor` while it return nothing.

```
book.changeAuthor("arulnathan")
fmt.Println(book.author)
```